# Does $f_0=x,f_{n+1}(x)=e^{1/f_n(x)}$ converge to $1/W(1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, functional-equations

**Question:** Define $f_0=x,f_{n+1}(x)=e^{1/f_n(x)}$ and $x\neq0$. What does this sequence of functions converge to as $n\to+\infty$? Is it true that $f_n(x)$ converges to the constant $\frac1{W(1)}$, where $W(x)$ is the Lambert W function?

**Attempt:** By plotting $f_n$ for high $n$, it seems to approach a constant function around $y\approx1.7$. By assuming that for sufficiently large $n$, $f_n=f_{n+1}$, and assuming that $f_n$ becomes constant, we can solve $f_n=e^{1/f_n}$ for $f_n=\frac{1}{W(1)}\approx1.763$.

**Context:** I was investigating the behaviour of $f_{n+1}(x)=g(f_n(x))$ for different $g(x)$ and found that $g(x)=e^{1/x}$ seemed to converge to a constant around $1.7$.

**Notes:** My attempt is by no means a rigorous proof. Is the limit of the sequence necessarily the solution of the functional equation $f(x)=e^{1/f(x)}$? And why should the limit be a constant? If anyone could direct me to a method for a proof or previous literature, I'd be appreciative. Thank you.

Comment: $g=e^{1/g}$ if the limit exists, equals $g>0$, so $g=\frac{1}{W(1)}$, so we just need to prove convergence. Hmm... Maybe we can prove convergence almost everywhere to $\frac{1}{W(1)}$?

Answer (score 1):

If the limit exists then it must be a fixed point of $f$ i.e. it must be some $x_0$ such that

$x_0 = e^{1 / x_0}$

Let $y_0=\frac{1}{x_0}$. Then

$\frac{1}{y_0} = e^{y_0}$

$\Rightarrow y_0 e^{y_0} = 1$

$\Rightarrow y_0=W(1)$

$\Rightarrow x_0 = \frac{1}{W(1)}$

So now you just need to prove that the limit exists. As a first step towards this, sketch the graph of $f(x)$ for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do we justify the limit being a fixed point?

Comment: Because $f(x)$ is continuous for $x \ne 0$. So if $\lim f_n(x) = x_0$ then $\lim f_{n+1}(x) = f(x_0)$. But $\lim f_{n+1}(x) = \lim f_n(x)$. And $f_n(x)$ can only have (at most) one limit.